# SQL Select distinct but return all columns plus where

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct, where-clause

I am trying to create a view where i list all columns but only make a distinct on [SERVER_NAME]
at the same time i only want to list from company = x and systems that are not retired.

i have tried to make a group by Server_name but get an error:

```
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [SYSTEM_ID]
      ,[SERVER_NAME]
      ,[COMPANY]
      ,[SYSTEM_OWNER]
      ,[SYSTEM_STATUS]
      ,[SERVER_STATUS]
      ,[PrimaryDnsName]
      ,[DomainName]
      ,[DiscoveredVendor]
      ,[IpAddress]
  FROM [ServerSystemDB].[dbo].[Server_System_Kunde]
 WHERE COMPANY = 'BM-ASK' and SYSTEM_STATUS != 'Retired'
-- GROUP BY [SERVER_NAME]
```

Since the SYSTEM_ID is not the same it lists the SERVER_NAME multiple times and thats the column that i need to be unique.

any suggestions?

Comment: Don't include SYSTEM_ID

Comment: As said by Blam, exclude SYSTEM_ID in your select clause and if you want to get rid of the DISTINCT keyword, you will need to group by all other column names listed in your select statement

Comment: Hmm yeah that makes sense, sometimes its not see the obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments my comment was the anser

Don't include SYSTEM_ID